# How do I reference contents of another jsp from a jsp include (per say a link)

Tags: html, jsp, include

How do I reference link contents of one jsp from a jsp include (per say a link)

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ include file="link.jsp"%>
<html>

    //can I get the link.jsp link from here with this include?

</html>
```

**link.jsp**

```
<html>
     <a href"someplace"></a>  <--I want this to be a reference to other jsps
</html>
```

Comment: What do u mean by reference to other jsp's ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. JSP doesn't offer any advanced templating capabilities like that. Best what you can get in JSP is the `<jsp:include>`, but it stops there. It get included exactly there where you declare it. You could at highest prepare some `String` values with HTML, but that's plain ugly and not maintainable. Better would be to render content conditionally using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:if>` and/or `<c:choose>` tags and so on.

If you're looking for a more advanced template framework, consider looking at [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/) or [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/). JSP's successor [Facelets](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) also provides more advanced templating capabilities, but it is more tied to the MVC framework JSF and probably not an option when you're already using a MVC framework of a different flavor.